# Wordpress - wp_options - widget option_value strucuture

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to understand the structure stored in the `option_value` column in the options table of wordpress database.

I didn't find any documentation, if you could share some links or some info about how to parse the structure it would be very helpful. Thanks ;)